# NodeJS unable to sucessfully decrypt C++ AES256 CBC string

Tags: c++, node.js, encryption, aes, node-crypto

Good evening all.

I have been trying to figure this out for literal days now but to no avail.

## Situation:

1. I am encrypting a string in C++ with OpenSSL's AES Lib. Then I am converting it to Base64 and sending it to my NodeJS Server for decryption.
2. The JS server correctly recieves the encoded data, but always fails the decryption, no matter how I set things up, or change settings, ect
3. I am using AES256 CBC
4. The C++ encrypt function **should** be replicating the desired behaviour of `PKCS#7` according to the documentation I have found about PKCS#7

## Relevant code blocks:

**C++ Code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>

#include "base64.h"

using namespace std;

// AES encryption key and IV (Initialization Vector)
const unsigned char aes_key[] = {
    "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"
};

unsigned char aes_iv[] = {
    "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"
};

string EncryptAES(const string& plainText) {
    AES_KEY enc_key;
    AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, 256, &enc_key);

    // Determine padding length
    int paddingLength = AES_BLOCK_SIZE - (plainText.length() % AES_BLOCK_SIZE);

    // If the plaintext length is already a multiple of the block size,
    // add a full block of padding
    if (paddingLength == 0) {
        paddingLength = AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
    }

    // Append padding bytes
    string paddedText = plainText;
    for (int i = 0; i < paddingLength; ++i) {
        paddedText.push_back((char)paddingLength);
    }

    // Encrypt padded plaintext
    string cipherText;
    cipherText.resize(paddedText.length());
    AES_cbc_encrypt((const unsigned char*)paddedText.c_str(), (unsigned char*)&cipherText[0], paddedText.length(), &enc_key, aes_iv, AES_ENCRYPT);

    return cipherText;
}

int main() {
    // Plain text message to encrypt
    string plainText = "Hello, this is a secret message.";

    // Encrypt the message using AES
    string encryptedText = EncryptAES(plainText);

    auto encodedText = base64_encode(encryptedText);

    std::cout << "Encoded text: " << encodedText << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Base64 Lib Used](https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/cpp-base64)

**NodeJS Server**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON and URL-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// AES decryption key and IV (Initialization Vector)
const aes_key = Buffer.from("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef", 'hex');
const aes_iv = Buffer.from("0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef", 'hex');

// AES decryption function
function DecryptAES(cipherText) {
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', aes_key, aes_iv);
    let decrypted = decipher.update(cipherText, 'base64', 'utf8');
    decrypted += decipher.final('utf8');
    return decrypted;
}

app.post('/decrypt', (req, res) => {
    const { encryptedText } = req.body;

    if (!encryptedText) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Missing encryptedText in request body' });
    }

    try {
        const decryptedText = DecryptAES(encryptedText);
        res.send(decryptedText);
        console.log(decryptedText);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Decryption failed:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Decryption failed');
    }
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**My Question:**
Does anyone know what is happening? As far as I can tell, the encryption works perfectly, but the NodeJS refuses to correctly decode anything. I am unsure where my problem lays and have run out of options. Thanks all.

## Behaviour:

- When the server attempts to decrypt the key, it results a `Bad Decrypt`
- If I use `dicipher.setAutoPadding(false)` it will incorrectly decrypt the string. (Will result in gibberish)
- When I use [an online AES decryptor](https://the-x.cn/en-US/cryptography/Aes.aspx) the string from the C++ code works perfectly
- Generating my own string (And encrypting ect) in NodeJS produces a different result to the C++ code (And websites)

**Notes:**

- I am sending the POST request via [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/download) for testing. Sending the required JSON body with the below content.
- I have a feeling the issue is related to how either the buffer is generated or decrypted, but none of my testing has produced any results so :/

**JSON Body**

```
{
    "encryptedText": "4oUys+a9EWvflSPZPxHYIfXcLV6wwisg7IlQ5a6Pa8CMkMiIwY2+ySMkQG351jJc"
}
```

Plain text = "Hello, this is a secret message." -> AES256_CBC -> Base64

Comment: Key and IV are hex encoded and are thus hex decoded in the NodeJS code. In the C code no hex decoding seems to take place (so that in the end a different key and IV is used in both codes). Also, it would probably be less error-prone not to use a low lever interface (`AES_set_encrypt_key()`, `AES_cbc_encrypt()`) but the corresponding high level interface, see [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption#Encrypting_the_message).

Comment: @Topaco I converted the key and IV to hex literal however it still produced the same result. Updating the encryption function to use the new SSL 3.0 EVP encryption also produced the same result. However, this makes sense considering that every online converter I have tried can also decrypt the c++ strings. Only the NodeJS code doesn't seem to work

Comment: A hex decoding of key and IV looks e.g. like this: `unsigned char aes_key[] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef}; unsigned char aes_iv[] = {0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef, 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef};`. If you run your C code with this, you will get a different ciphertext.

Comment: Your C code, in contrast, performs an ASCII (or UTF-8) encoding of the key, resulting in a 64 bytes key, of which only the first half is used in further processing. The same applies to the IV. You can easily verify this by using as key and IV: `unsigned char aes_key[] = {"0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef"}; unsigned char aes_iv[] = {"0123456789abcdef"};` which gives the *same* ciphertext (proving that only the first half of key and IV are taken into account).

Comment: Whether you hex decode or ASCII encode key and IV (the ASCII encoding in conjunction with implicit or explicit truncation) ultimately depends on your requirements. However, for the codes to be compatible, this must be *consistent* in both codes. This is currently not the case. Currently, it is ASCII encoded (and implicitly truncated) in the C code and hex decoded in the NodeJS code, which is why decryption fails.

Comment: Regarding the online tool: You are making the same mistake as in the C code: Key and IV are entered as strings, are thus ASCII encoded and intransparently truncated by the tool. I recommend a more reliable and *transparent* online tool, e.g. CyberChef, s. [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef'%7D,%7B'option':'UTF8','string':'0123456789abcdef'%7D,'CBC','Raw','Raw',%7B'option':'Hex','string':''%7D)To_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D')&input=SGVsbG8sIHRoaXMgaXMgYSBzZWNyZXQgbWVzc2FnZS4) for the ASCII/UTF-8 encoding case.

Comment: @Topaco Wow you are a legend. You're absolutely correct. I didn't even realise how the encoding was done so I was using completely wrong byte arrays. Thanks for the help mate